# How to deal with App ids when contributing to iOS open source projects

Tags: ios, xcode, git, open-source

I want to make some changes to an open source iOS project. The problem is when I try to use my provisioning profile to build and run the app on my device, Xcode 7 complains: `An App ID with Identifier 'com.whoisryannystrom.hackernews' is not available. Please enter a different string`.

The app is published and the bundle identifier is reserved by another team that is clear. I see the only way to solve this is to change the identifier, commit that change, and later before making pull request revert that commit.

Is there any better way of dealing with the bundle identifier for open source projects?